# How to authenticate user in microservice architecture with Lumen

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, microservices, lumen

I'm new to microservice architecture. I was reading about it and start to be interested in developing website using the architecture. *I've used Lumen micro framework.*

What I am going to ask you has been browsed on the internet and I couldn't find the way. So, I finally reached out to stackoverflow. Below is the overview of my current implementation.

[image: overview of my current implementation using microservice architecture]

Up until this point, I am able to request user, patient, treatment, etc.. data from the api gateway and get the response data properly.

When client requests user data like name, department, client requests this route, http://localhost:8000/users/1, (port 8000 is for api gateway and 8001 for user service, let's say) and gateway goes to 8001 and grab the user data.

I've also enabled the authorization between api gateway and individual services in order to prevent separately perform CRUD operatons to the individual services - when request goes from gateway to service, I have put the pregenerated token (which is also predefined in the service) in the header and when it reaches the service, the service validates if the token is equal by comparing its predefined one. So, it's working.

But to be able to request from api gateway to services, I've used **client credentials** grant type. So, here is my question.

> How can I implement the login and register? Does client credentials
>   grant type enable to do so? If not, what is the appropriate one? What
>   is the right way to implement the system? Could you please kindly explain in
>   advance? Thank you so much.

**Updated**
In conclusion, I want to know how to configure authentication between front-end and api gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Your API architecture looks good - nothing there needs to change. However there are 3 parts to the architecture:

- APIs (done)
- UIs (to do)
- Authorization Server (maybe use a free cloud one?)

As a next step maybe focus on login. My [tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/) will help you to understand the interaction and what needs to be coded in UIs. Or if you prefer just view the [message workflow](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/).

Registering users can be a more complex topic and depends on the type of system. Happy to answer follow up questions if it helps.

Comment: Thank you Gary. I'm using React for my front-end. What about authorization server? Do I need to use third-party one? Can't I make it myself? And please mention your free cloud ones.

Comment: For your React UI I'd recommend plugging in the oidc client library to do the work for you - as in my tutorial. An authorization server is a complex and critical component so don't build your own. Maybe start with [Okta](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/)  as in my case (free developer version) or use AWS Cognito (free unless you have a high volume of requests). If you code your UI and API in the right way you can easily swap providers later.